# jquery/js split - does not split string completly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, split

i have an ajax call which gets data in string de-limited format

```
9!!18!!30!!0!!dfsdfsdf!!sdfsdfs!!555-555-3410!!!!dfda@yahoo.com
!!0000-00-00!!!!08/03/2015~~Test 1!!Hot!!08/09/2015~~Hot~~~~08/08/2015~~Warm~~~~08/08/2015~~Hot~~~~07
/30/2015-New!!08/07/2015~~zzdf dfdfsdfsdfsdfdf!!0000-00-00!!DFW!!700!!!!08/07/2015~~dfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
~~~~08/07/2015~~cCZcZXCxzcxzc~~~~08/07/2015~~hggfhfghfghfghg~~~~08/07/2015~~kjhkjhhjjkkjhk~~~~08/03/2015
~~This is a Test~~~~Second <br />
How old: 3 years<br />
Details: dfsdfsdfs thdfdfsdfsd!!0000-00-00!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!0000-00-00!!!!0000-00-00!!08/07/2015~~czxcc zczcxz
 z c zc zxczxc!!0000-00-00!!0000-00-00!!!!!!!!1
```

I am using "!!" to de limit the various data fields. the above is what is returned in the firebug response tab

on the jquery front i ma using

```
 var lead_val=lead_data.split('!!'); 
 console.log(lead_val);
```

the result i get is

```
["9", "18", "30", "0", "sdsdfsdf", "dsfsdfsd", "555-555-3410", "", "sdfdsfsd@yahoo.com", "0000-00-00", "", "08/03/2015"]
```

as you can see al lteh fields are not split only the first few are.

the problem was **solved** when i used urlencode (in the php script).... the reason i posted this was to understand why the split was not working if i didn't use url encode (lets call it inane curiosity) ...

Comment: it is working fine with split, see http://jsfiddle.net/fedqtfks/

Comment: where is "sdfdsfsd@yahoo.com" in your data ? you don't have show us the good test data